# React.js: use node js modules in components?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, module, electron

In my component I need a module ipcRenderer. I'm trying to get it:

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
console.log(ipcRenderer)
```

but the result is:

```
[1] ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js
[1] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\steko\Desktop\DEV\crab\node_modules\electron'
[1]  @ ./node_modules/electron/index.js 1:9-22
[1]  @ ./src/components/PageCatalogLinks.jsx
[1]  @ ./src/components/ContentBlock.jsx
[1]  @ ./src/index.jsx
```

How to fix?

I tried to add a model fs, but he already is.